# How to display a category from a specific post-type

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

I have a custom post type called "my_people" along with a custom taxonomy named my_people_categories.  It is used to display a list of people.  I would like to show only the people in the list that are in a specific category in the custom taxonomy.

I have tried using the following short code, but it displays all the people and not just the ones in the categories named.

```
[catlist name=cat1,cat2 post_type=my_people orderby=title order=ASC]
```

Is there someway I am supposed to mention the taxonomy?  Is what I am trying to do even possible using this addon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [the list of supported parameters](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/other_notes/) you can possibly use it with a custom post type by setting `post_type` to `any`, but it doesn't appear to support custom taxonomies.

Comment: I decided to roll my own plugin to do what i needed to do.  Thanks for the info!